# cordova/phonegap platform android

Tags: android, cordova, ant

Ok here it goes, I want to use phonegap alright? Yeah it sounds good, awesome yeah whatever. Oh important thing, I'm running on windows 7 x64. Right we got that cleared out.

### FAQ

Q1: Did I get java sdk (yeah not jre - jdk!)? Yes got it!

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
```

Q2: What about ant? That too!

```
C:\apache-ant-1.9.3
```

Q3: Ok nice, then where's the android sdk? Everything right here: (got the android developer tools)

```
C:\adt
```

Q4: Hmm alright... Wait let me cut you right there. The system variables, ah yup, got them!

```
ANDROID_HOME --> C:\adt\sdk
ANT_HOME --> C:\apache-ant-1.9.3
JAVA_HOME --> C:\Program Files\jdk1.7.0_51
XCOPY --> C:\Windows\System32
PATH --> %XCOPY%;%ANDROID_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\adt\sdk\platform-tools;C:\adt\sdk\tools
```

### MY PROBLEM

1st problem: I run the `android` command but nothing works.

2nd problem: Let me break it into steps:

1. `cordova platform add android` that's working
2. `phonegap install android` Not Working
3. `phonegap run android` Nope

Whichever I try running in order to compile. It just won't work... I get the following error:

```
$ phonegap local run android
[phonegap] compiling Android...
   [error] An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant debug -f "C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Projects\buddytalk\platforms\android\build.xml"":
BUILD FAILED
C:\adt\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:932: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\adt\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:950: null returned: 1

Total time: 11 seconds
```

ant seems to be the problem right now...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Permissions issue on the adt dir?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon sorry not sure how to check that? I mean yup I know right click under properties but then what?

Comment: Sorry, I've been in mac land too long. You will want to make sure the folder is fully accessible to your user and any admin/system role. Some info on how to do that here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-do-i-change-folder-and-file-permissions/465f2b42-63dd-4486-8dd1-c870290efeed

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Alright thanks, will check it out.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon It gave me another error, but this time related to node_modules. Then when I tries running it again it gave me the error as above. Is there a way to exclude the node_modules or should I just delete it when I build?

Comment: Do you have node installed?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon sorry for late answer. Yes I have node installed. I meant that I got a node_modules folder in the www directory. That's the reason why it failed to compile. But once I take it off it builds. It's strange that once I run "phonegap run android" the build is alright, but I can't seem to find the apk file and also I can't emulate, not sure why. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. You use Cordova? Good !
2. Why are you mixing them?
3. Why are you mixing them?

Just keep using one of the two, I personally suggest Cordova, if you are not using Phonegap build.

Comment: the only reason that I got mixed them up was because when I ran the command "phonegap run android", an error would come up saying that I have don't have android installed (in the platform folder) and it would say to use "cordova platform add android" in order to get the actual platform first. So I got mixed up. Later on I tried "phonegap install android". In conclusion, I would bump into that same error. Just found out after DawsonLoudon proposed to change the permission, it worked.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I'll use the "cordova" command instead then because I won't be using phonegap build. One more question, I can't seem to find the apk file once I run "cordova build android". Is there a solution to that? Thanks

Comment: So far I have only work with iOS, but I suppose the apk could be located somewhere inside the android platform folder, but I suspect you already search for it there...

Comment: Hi @VicM, yup I found it. Thanks for the help. I just want ask one last question. If I want to add plugins to my application, should I use plugman or should I stick to cordova? Thanks

Comment: Cordova mate, using the CLI, refers to the doc it really have examples for almost all. It is worth reading.